# Can I select all child elements of a specific element with a specific class without writing a list of selectors for each child?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a html-body like in the following code-snippet:

```css
div.element>h1, h2, p {
  color: red
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="1">
    <div class="element">
      <h1>Test 1</h1>
      <span>Link to interesting <a href="https://google.com">site A</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="2">
    <div class="element">
      <h2>Test 2</p>
      <span>Link to interesting <a href="https://google.com">site B</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="3">
    <div class="element">
      <h3>Dont color me red!</h3>
      <p>Test 3</p>
      <span>Link to interesting <a href="https://google.com">site C</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <h2>This is my footer</h2>
    <p>Do not color this text red!</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I would like to color all "*h1*", "*h2*" and "*p*" elements that are a child of a "*div*" with *class="element"* in red. This means that the "*h2*" and "*p*" in the footer-div should not be colored red since they are not a child of a *div* with *class="element"*.

I am aware that I could solve it like the following but there is a lot of repetition.

```
div.element>h1, div.element>h2, div.element>p {}
```

Is there any other way to select children of a div with different tags?

*Note that I do not want any answers suggesting changes to the body of my html document. I am only interested in the css-selector.
I also need to be able to select it in JavaScript using querySelectorAll.*

Comment: So your questions boils down to is there something more succinct than `div.element>h1, div.element>h2, div.element>p {}`?

Comment: if you only want `h1` `h2` and `p` under the `.element` then you can only use the selector you already know. If you want any child of the `.element` you could use `.element > *`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli sorry that would not work. I also have other elements in there that should not be colored in red. Let me update my question

Comment: then the `div.element>h1, div.element>h2, div.element>p {}` is the way to go. you could also omit the `div` part if you know where the `.element` class will be applied. So `.element>h1, .element>h2, .element>p {}`. Depending on how you build your code you could use a css pre-processor like `less` or `sass`.

Comment: In the future you could use the [`:is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) selector, which now requires vendor prefixes so it defeats the purpose of writing less code.

Comment: In the example, the elements you want to style are each the first in the div. If that is a consistent pattern, i.e. if everything you want to color is the first child in its parent, you can write `.element >*::first-child` for a selector.

Comment: @MrLister sorry not the case again. Will update that too

Comment: If you want more succinct tidier code for CSS you could always look into SASS. In SASS it would look like so:

.element {
  h1, h2, p {
    color: red
  }
}

Comment: @IndustryDesigns then that wouldn't work with ".querySelector" in JavaScript right?

Comment: Yes, it would all still work completely the same in JS.

Comment: @IndustryDesigns would you like to write that as an answer then? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `querySelectorAll`, like you say in the comments to the first answer (which wasn't clear in your question), then the solution is to use two `querySelectorAll`s in sequence.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.element').forEach(
  el => el.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, p').forEach(
    el => el.style.color = 'red'
  )
);
```

```css
.footer {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="1">
    <div class="element">
      <h1>Test 1</h1>
      <span>Link to interesting <a href="https://google.com">site A</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="2">
    <div class="element">
      <h2>Test 2</p>
      <span>Link to interesting <a href="https://google.com">site B</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="3">
    <div class="element">
      <h3>Dont color me red!</h3>
      <p>Test 3</p>
      <span>Link to interesting <a href="https://google.com">site C</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <h2>This is my footer</h2>
    <p>Do not color this text red!</p>
  </div>
```

But at that point it might be more straightforward to just use `div.element>h1, div.element>h2, div.element>p` in the stylesheet instead.

Answer (score 1):

Within vanilla CSS, the cleanest you can select the required items inside the `<div>` element, is like so

```
.element h1, .element h2, .element p {}
```

If you want more succinct tidier code for CSS you could always look into SASS.

In SASS it would look like so:

```
.element { 
  h1, h2, p { 
    color: red 
  } 
}
```

You can find SASS here: https://sass-lang.com/

Selecting in JS will not change based on using a preprocessor. All the preprocessor does is allow you to write CSS in a certain way, then converts it to normal CSS for the browser to read.

Hence if you want to select .element h1, .element h2, .element p in the cleanest way via JS, I would give those specific elements a class, for instance "red", and then use this class in JS to select them.

Comment: So in js I would write .querySelectorAll(".element {h1, h2, p}")?

Comment: Defenitely thanks for the answer, very interesting. I have never heard of it. Unfortunately, we are not willing to bind an entire css-extension for such a little problem but it's good to know for other projects...